# Mockito: Mock a method which manipulates an input array parameter

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito

How do I mock a method which takes an int array as input and manipulates the array elements? I believe we can do that with doAnswer() but I'm not able to represent the input type there.

```
class View {
  public void getLocationOnScreen(int[] location) {
    //this method assigns elements of the array.
    location[0] = 5;
    location[1] = 6;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                int[] location = (int[]) args[0];
                return location;
            }
        }).when(view).getLocationOnScreen(Matchers.any(int []));
```

Comment: This works. Only a small change. Instead of saying "Matchers.any()", I had to pass an integer array.

Answer (score 2):

Look if this is what you expect:

```
@Test
public void getLocationOnScreen() throws Exception {
    View mockView = mock(View.class);

    // Prepare the integer array to test.
    int[] location = new int[2];

    // Verify interactions
    mockView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    verify(mockView).getLocationOnScreen(location);

    // Stub voids
    doAnswer(new Answer() {
        @Override
        public int[] answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            int[] args = (int[])(invocation.getArguments()[0]);
            args[0] = 5;
            args[1] = 6;
            return args;
        }
    }).when(mockView).getLocationOnScreen(location);

    // Asserts
    mockView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    assertEquals(5, location[0]);
    assertEquals(6, location[1]);
}
```

Comment: Same as Ahmed's answer but more elaborated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you do the mock, the test will not pass through that method. So you do not really care about the logic in that method you just will return a kind of object that you would wait.

Your location is a void method so it won't return anything. So you just need to do something like this:

Mockito.when (getLocationOnScreen(Mockito.any(int[].class));

Comment: I need to set mock values to the elements of the array when that method is invoked. These updated elements of the array are used in further logic after calling the getLocationOnScreen method. So I believe there should be someway to mock the elements of the array while calling that method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a cleaner way with lambda expressions

```
  doAnswer(invocation -> {
            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
            int[] location = (int[]) args[0];
            return location;
        }).when(view).getLocationOnScreen(Matchers.any(int []));
```